# Creating dynamic declaration of array

Tags: c, arrays, variables, dynamic, declaration

I want make array which will be declared dynamically I imagine something like this. I want make program that recognize characters in the word.

```
char i;
scanf("%c",&i);
char word[]=i;
printf("%c",word[0]);
```

I also tried something like this:

```
char i;
scanf(%c,&i);
char *word=i;
printf("%c",word[0]);
```

I have no clue how to make it work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Declaring arraz with dynamic content](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33455240/declaring-arraz-with-dynamic-content)

Answer (score 2):

Let's just start with the basics. What you are declaring when your write:

```
char word[]=i;
```

is an *array of characters* which will be initialized based on what is to the right of the `=` sign. In this case to `i` which is a single character (even though that technically is an invalid initializer). So essentially you are attempting to declare a character array of size `1`.

If that were allowed, `word` would not a character *string* because it was not (and could not be) `null-terminated`. It is simply an array of type char and cannot be used as a string. (note `char word[]="i";` would work - and be null-terminated)

When you declare `word` as:

```
char *word=i;
```

you have created a *pointer to type char* that is *incorrectly* initialized to hold the memory address of `i`.

(a pointer simply contains, as its value, the address for something else stored in memory, in this case you have set that address to the value of `i` which likely is in the system reserved range of memory and will probably cause an immediate segmentation fault.

What you probably intended was:

```
char *word=&i;
```

Where you store the *address of* `i` as the value of word. While this will give you a character pointer to `i`, it has nothing to do with dynamic allocation beyond involving a pointer.

To properly allocate `word` dynamically, you do still need to create a pointer named `word`, but you then need to allocate a block of memory that `word` will point to. (pointing to the starting address for that block of memory). So to dynamically allocate space for `word` you would expect to see something like:

```
char *word = NULL;            /* initialization to NULL is good practice */
word = malloc (numbytes * sizeof *word); /* allocate numbytes of storage */
```

You then have a pointer `word` whose value is the starting address of the new block of memory of (`numbytes x sizeof *word`) bytes in size. (since `sizeof *word` is simply the `sizeof (char)` its value is `1`). So you have created a block of memory `numbytes` in size.

You have two responsibilities regarding that block of memory (1) you must preserve a pointer to the starting address of that block; so (2) you can `free` the memory when it is no longer needed. (1) means no `word++;, etc..` in your code. If you need to iterate a pointer value, create a pointer, e.g.:

```
char *p = word;
```

Then you can use pointer arithmetic on `p` without effecting the value of `word`.

You can then fill word any way you like as long as you leave room for a null-terminator at the end (if you are going to use it as a string) and don't attempt to write more than `numbytes` worth of data to it.

So in your case, if your intent was to dynamically allocate `word` to hold the character `i` to be printed as a string, you could easily do:

```
char *word = NULL;

word = malloc (10 * sizeof *word);
if (!word) {  /* always validate each allocation */
    fprintf (stderr, "error: virtual memory exhausted.\n");
    return 1;
}

if (scanf ("9%s", word))
    printf ("word contains '%s'\n", word);

free (word);
```

Note: that when using `scanf ("9%s", word)`, you will stop reading as soon as the first space is encountered. You may want to use `scanf ("9%[^\n]%*c", word)` which essentially says `%9[^\n]` *read up to 9 characters (that do NOT include a `\n`)*, then `%*c` *read and discard* the newline *without* adding it to the *match count* returned by `scanf`. So your test:

```
if (scanf ("9%s", word))
```

insures `scanf` has read at least one character into `word` as a string (null-terminating word) which on successful read is added to the *match count* for `scanf` making the `match count = 1`. The match count is then returned by `scanf` insuring that you only print after a successful read.

Note also: the number of character `scanf` will read is limited to `9` by including a width specifier `%9s` (or `%9[^\n]`) in the format string. This insures you cannot write beyond the end of the memory allocated to word while guaranteeing space available to null-terminate the string.

One other nit. If you are expecting a user to enter data, then *prompt* the user to enter the data, so the user isn't left looking at a blinking cursor on the screen, wondering if the program got hung up, etc..  Putting all this together in a short example.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main (void) {

    char *word = NULL;

    word = malloc (10 * sizeof *word);
    if (!word) {  /* always validate each allocation */
        fprintf (stderr, "error: virtual memory exhausted.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    printf ("\nEnter up to 9 characters to store in 'word': ");
    if (scanf ("%9[^\n]%*c", word))
        printf ("word contains '%s'\n", word);

    free (word);

    return 0;
}
```

**Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/dynalloc

Enter up to 9 characters to store in 'word': dog
word contains 'dog'

$ ./bin/dynalloc

Enter up to 9 characters to store in 'word': 1234567890
word contains '123456789'

$ ./bin/dynalloc

Enter up to 9 characters to store in 'word': my dog
word contains 'my dog'
```

Let me know if you have any questions.